# What is the fundamental difference between "PlotPoints" and "MaxRecursion"?

Tags: plotting, options

When making a plot,

> PlotPoints

or

> MaxRecursion

options are used to specify the accuracy or the extent of how detailed the result will be.

Ff either of them do the similar job, I think only one option of the two is enough for the purpose.

Then, why the two are used in Mathematica?
What is the fundamental difference between them?

Comment: FYI the [documentation for Plot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) states it fairly clearly - *"Plot initially evaluates f at a number of equally spaced sample points specified by PlotPoints. Then it uses an adaptive algorithm to choose additional sample points, subdividing a given interval at most MaxRecursion times. "*

Comment: The practical issue is which of the two to use when, in order to improve quality (and perhaps fidelity) of a given plot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`PlotPoints` guarantees a number of points that will be plotted.  `MaxRecursion` states the *maximum* recursion, which might not be needed or used in a given plot.  If I'm plotting a large number of functions—some simple, some complex—then I use `MaxRecursion` so as to speed the plotting of "simple" graphs.

Moreover, `PlotPoints` generally places the points equally spaced while `MaxRecursion` effectively places the extra detail in positions of the plot with rapidly changing function, as is evident in the small-$x$ values in the graph:  `Plot[Sin[1/x], {x, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I may ask, what do you mean by "with large oscillations" in "MaxRecursion effectively places the extra detail in positions of the plot with large oscillations."?

Comment: @SmartHumanism:  Look at `Plot[Sin[1/x], {x, 0, 1}]`.  For values to the right, the curve is smooth, so you might need points at values such as $x = .9, .91, .92, ...$.  Look at the left of the graph.  The function varies so rapidly that you must use points such as $x = .1, .1000001, .1000002, .1000003, ...$.

Comment: Thank you very much.